# How to align groupbox horizontally centered along with scroll view in qml

Tags: qt, qml, groupbox

I am facing trouble in aligning group boxes to horizontally centered along with scrollview in Qml.

I have tried anchors.horizontalCentre: Qt.AlignHCenter and Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter.
But none of them works.
Please find below sample code which aligns horizontally left.

```
ApplicationWindow {
id: root
width: 500
height: 100
visible: true

ScrollView {
    anchors.fill: parent
    clip: true
    ScrollBar.vertical.policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn

    ColumnLayout { //Arrange GroupBox's in column wise
        anchors.fill: parent
        spacing: 10
        anchors.margins: 10
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter

        GroupBox {
            title: qsTr("Sample1")

            ColumnLayout { //Arrange child Items in column wise
                Text { id: gr1text1; text: qsTr("Group 1, Text 1") }
                Text { id: gr1text2; text: qsTr("Group 1, Text 2") }
            }
        }

        GroupBox {
            title: qsTr("Sample2")

            ColumnLayout { //Arrange child Items in column wise
                Text { id: gr2text1; text: qsTr("Group 2, Text 1") }
                Text { id: gr2text2; text: qsTr("Group 2, Text 2") }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

The output of the above code is captured below

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a couple of changes:

1. Replace `ScrollView` with `Flickable`
2. Configure the `Flickable` to take the width from the children, but, the height from the parent item. We do this, because you indicated the need for a vertical `ScrollBar` so the height cannot be taken from the children
3. Configure the `Flickable` to have the anchors for horizontal alignment
4. Apply `ScrollBar.vertical` to `Flickable` and set the width to `20` pixels for a fat scrollbar
5. Set the `contentWidth` and `contentHeight` to the parent `ColumnLayout`. Doing this helps the `ScrollBar` work out the geometry of the content versus the geometry of the `Flickable`

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    Flickable {
        id: flickable
        anchors.fill: parent
        clip: true
        contentWidth: columnLayout.width
        contentHeight: columnLayout.height
        ScrollBar.vertical : ScrollBar {
            width: 20
            policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
        }
        ColumnLayout {
            id: columnLayout
            width: flickable.width
            spacing: 10
            GroupBox {
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
                title: qsTr("Sample1")
                ColumnLayout { //Arrange child Items in column wise
                    Text { id: gr1text1; text: qsTr("Group 1, Text 1") }
                    Text { id: gr1text2; text: qsTr("Group 1, Text 2") }
                }
            }
            GroupBox {
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
                title: qsTr("Sample2")
                ColumnLayout { //Arrange child Items in column wise
                    Text { id: gr2text1; text: qsTr("Group 2, Text 1") }
                    Text { id: gr2text2; text: qsTr("Group 2, Text 2") }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAAEq3icvVJdb8IgFH3vryA+bclSVx7Zk5psLlmyGU32zBBbMgoM6NQs/e+7WK39UJPtwfsC93C4nHNakRttPZr5WSHYZyRabTzRylstXRd/oVtdeBe90ZSjnwhBPUo4oB/y0IcSS4JWB7xGqWKZti5eCSkJMtRy5etDJoUhyNviyGcgAijvYukzAp0sclUJiNcB6xKnXKSZ7zCzHVhT5wxsyTG18Te3XjAqETmCDQuh1tXL+L6FGg3Oto1b8Uiu6da9qppW1rtJQ0tnegipKfXU03WIHcehnKFMqJSgpK3vyerCjPWm81yofSZUilTlkBiBDwvqoZtOoOW2d8MLLzlBX25hbwZzmhvJk8Ftj9a2iYbDkbVUwT/CMiGX6Nnz3CGh9n7BneO9GaEWfBPuh2hSm3jokgcUloOEnTmU3FVMkNLI+vIgfGkQPjmojZRXTRlfK2V8NmX8t5Tx2ZTxv1KudmVU/gJwZURS)

Also, consider using `ListView` since it has a natural ability to apply a `ScrollBar`. The following example demonstrates how your example can be expressed using a `ListView` with a `model`:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        width: contentItem.childrenRect.width + 20
        height: parent.height
        model: [ {
            title: qsTr("Sample 1"),
            text1: qsTr("Group 1, Text 1"),
            text2: qsTr("Group 1, Text 2")
        }, {
            title: qsTr("Sample 2"),
            text1: qsTr("Group 2, Text 1"),
            text2: qsTr("Group 2, Text 2")
        } ]
        clip: true
        spacing: 10
        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
            policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
            width: 20
        }
        delegate: GroupBox {
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            title: modelData.title
            ColumnLayout {
                Text { text: modelData.text1 }
                Text { text: modelData.text2 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAADkniclVKxTsMwEN3zFVYnKiqLZMxGi4SQKkFpxYIYLNckJ5zY2BfaUuXfcdLWTawM4YbI9+7Fd373oNDKIFnhqgL+FUEvpQtVolHShviSHVSFNnphmSDHiLhYgsU3ELtz2gQrea6MpZ8gZUo0M6JEX9zBFvOUcNfBwU8oCspzkFtHehUcaVsntyS587/kArIcLzfRU+qrhdoK1+a9M0ATCChFSr7txtxM1qzQUpB4Mp31SWKP8YX0aFSlSTwjG4cOc5NhbjKZemo9GzFIMmKQ5B+DJEODkA9/5hJ0StBUwkNWMw5llpL4KvSau6XLOTP0RxgEzpyuHguepZUEfujU6b3csYN9Lnu087o726z9ye1NZAydOO0r5mof9LgYyX3g1xmGyYUzgDBXKwSFIeFbfzwwZLQFepSFklVRnlwd9G6i1fTYCt67p1lW5x0j6ElArwM56qj+A4kN+l0=)

Comment: Thank you Stephen Quan for your solution.
Will it wont be possible to align with ScrollView ?